# database design for large streaming data with minimal latency

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql, cassandra

Following is the scenario:
Customer places an order. 
Order has type: Physical / Downloadable.
Order is placed from: Web / App.
Order is placed from a Location: UK,AUS,etc.
Can have more dimensions in future.

Consider that all of the dimensions change frequently in every order. And the data is quite huge, approximately 1.3 million records per hour.

Want to design this in a way that reports should be able able to drill down with any requested dimension for each customer.

Example:
- Customer 'A' has placed how many orders of type 'Physical' from 'AUS'
- Customer 'A' has placed how many orders in all.
- Customer 'A' has placed how many orders from of type 'Downloadable' from'APP'.
etc.

Need these reports on realtime, hence low latency writes and reads are a must. What nosql database can be a good fit. And how can this data be well structured to be able to sliced and diced in any required dimension as well as combination of more than one dimension.

Answer (score 0):

If you need high performance then I would recommend [ScyllaDB](http://scylladb.com) which can handle over [1M ops/s per node](http://www.scylladb.com/2015/10/09/single-node-benchmark-1-8m-tps/) (on a good hardware). It shares data model with Cassandra so you can model and query your data using CQL. You can give it a free test drive with just couple of clicks [here](http://scylladb.com.staging.tenrec.com/test-drive/).

Regarding modeling: A useful technique is to model around your queries. So if you have a particular query you should prepare a table that will serve this query in most efficient way. In this technique you duplicate data by creating as many tables with the same data as many different types of queries you have. Duplicating data comes with a price so you need to trade off the performance and cost depending on your needs. You can read more about it [here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling).